# Nuxt 3 SSR external webservice call in component

Tags: server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I've been trying to learn NuXT. My idea is to do all servicecalls on the server, and reply to the frontend with prerendered HTML. For that I've been looking for examples of SSR in nuxt 3.

The only example I've found is this: https://www.thisdot.co/blog/nuxt-3-demo-app-with-prerender-and-ssr but it doesnt seem to work.
Most other examples I can find is with SSR service calls in pages, not in components.

Is it good practice to make components do service calls and prerender in SSR for nuxt 3?
If yes, can you provide examples of how it would work?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be looking for [standalone server components](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components#standalone-server-components). From their docs:

> Standalone server components will always be rendered on the server, also known as Islands components.
> When their props update, this will result in a network request that will update the rendered HTML in-place.

Comment: I tried this, and I couldnt make it work. Do you know if there's other examples apart from the docs?

Comment: You're wondering if there are other examples of standalone server components?

Comment: I tried doing as described in the link, but it doesnt seem to work: https://github.com/b-runz/nuxt-3-example